# передача данных при promise

Tags: reactjs, promise

у меня есть код

```
function Detail() {
    const { productId } = useParams();
    const item = useSelector((state) => state.item);
    const {id, imageUrl, name, desc, types, length, price} = item;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
debugger
    const fetchOneApi = async (id) => {
        let arr = [];
        let temp = {};
        const response = await axios
        .get('http://localhost:3000/db.json')
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(('Err', err));
        })
        .then(response => {arr = response.data.weapon})
        .then (()=>{temp = arr.find(a => a.id === Number(productId))})
        .then(console.log(temp))
        .then(dispatch(selectedWeapon(()=>{arr.find(a => a.id === Number(productId))})))

        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        debugger
        if(productId && productId !== '') fetchOneApi(productId);

    }, [productId])

    return (
        <div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            {productId}
            {name}
            {desc}
            Detail
        </div>
    )
}
export default Detail
```

в строке

```js
.then(dispatch(selectedWeapon(arr.filter(a => a.id === Number(productId)))))
```

как я понимаю должен вызываться метод selectedWeapon, в который должен быть положен один item из arr если написать эту конструкцию `arr.filter(a => a.id === Number(productId)))` в console.log, то нет проблем этот item отображается, а вот передаваться в метод selectedWeapon этот item никак не хочет, может здесь что-то с then, подскажите кто знает, уже многое перепробовал

Answer (score 1):

`.filter` возвращает массив, вам я понял нужен элемент. Так что воспользуйтесь методом `.find` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: я поменял метод - не помогло, сейчас я поправи метод, я создал переменную temp и туда по моему мнению должен положиться объект, но этого не происходит, если вывести temp в консоль, то там оказывается пустой объект, может есть ещё мысли, в чём может быть проблема?